# Temporarily change font encoding with fontenc

Tags: font-encodings

Is there a way to temporarily change the font encoding with `fontenc` inside a document? Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
I'm writing something with OT1 encoding here.
But then I want the character X to be with T1 encoding.
\end{document}
```

---

I'm anticipating some "Why do you want to do this?" questions. So here's why:

With OT1 encoding, using the `libertine` package gives me certain nice ligatures (like the one for `Th`). I don't with T1 encoding (no idea why). But some characters aren't available with OT1 encoding, such as `\dh`, so I would like to temporarily switch to T1 encoding to be able to use such characters.

Comment: You can use `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
```

then

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont  T1 stuff ...}
```

full example, following comments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

That {\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont That}

\end{document}
```

The log confirms the fonts used and the OT1 ligature

```
....\OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 � (ligature Th)
....\OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 t
....\glue 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.833
....\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 T
....\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 h
....\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 a
....\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10 t
```

Comment: Turns out that by adding ``T1`` as an option in the preamble, I lose the ligature for ``Th``, which was the only reason I used the encoding ``OT1`` in the first place. Is there a way to activate the ``T1`` encoding _only_ for selected characters?

Comment: @Sverre see update: it works for me. (texlive 2013)

Comment: @Sverre: Are you sure you set T1 as the first option and OT1 after it?

Comment: I found out why that happened. The order of the encoding options in the preamble matters. Setting ``[T1, OT1]`` gives default OT1 encoding, setting ``[OT1, T1]`` gives default T1 encoding. I had the wrong order (yours was right).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Exactly :)