# \renewcommand and \newcommand for accented letters

Tags: macros, accents

I'm using OT1 font encoding, but I would like to use T1 font encoding for glyphs that don't exist in OT1. To do that, I'm redefining the typical T1 commands so that they automatically choose a T1 encoding. With the commands for accented letters, however, like `\'e` for `é`, using `\newcommand{\'e}` won't work because `\'` is already defined, but I can't use `\renewcommand{\'e}` either, since the full sequence `\'e` is not already defined.

Suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1, OT1]{fontenc}
%\newcommand{\'e}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont{\symbol{233}}} <- gives 'Command \' already defined' error
%\renewcommand{\'e}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont{\symbol{233}}} <- gives '\'eundefined' error
\begin{document}
\'e
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Given all the comments about the OT1 vs. T1 encoding, here's the contents of the OT1 and T1 fonts for `libertine`. One can see here that the OT1 font has some ligatures the T1 font doesn't have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{LinLibertineT-lf-ot1} % OT1 encoding
\fonttable{LinLibertineT-lf-t1} % T1 encoding
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the aim here: LaTeX gives you a combined accent and e in OT1 here already, while if you want to have a single glyph, you can just use T1 generally. What is the reason for wanting to use OT1/T1 in this way?

Comment: This has no advantage, other than, perhaps, getting a sligthly better output; but you'll be mixing different fonts, so hyphenation will still not be possible.

Comment: @JosephWright: My reasons for wanting to use OT1 generally are explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130541/temporarily-change-font-encoding-with-fontenc. In short, OT1 has some glyphs T1 doesn't have, and T1 has some glyphs OT1 doesn't have. The OT1 combination of accent+e is ugly in the ``libertine`` font, so I want to use the T1 non-combined glyph.

Comment: @Sverre Why don't you use T1 and forget about all the rest?

Comment: @egreg: Because then I lose some of the OT1 glyphs I want, which in the ``libertine`` font includes some nice ligatures missing from T1.

Comment: @Sverre I'd say the right solution is to track down and fix what is up with `libertine` in this case, then. Really OT1 is only there for 'stability' reasons.

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm not sure what you mean. The ``libertine`` OT1 font has some ligatures the T1 font doesn't have. There's nothing I can do to "fix" that. It's just a fact about the font package.

Comment: On the problem as posed, `\'e` is a command followed by a letter. As such, you'll need to redefine `\'` with knowledge of which letters it should fork for. Can you give us a list of the desired ones?

Comment: @Sverre The font sources must have the correct ligatures, so something is up with converting them to TeX format. That should get fixed.

Comment: @JosephWright Right now I can think of é, ó, ä, and ö ...

Comment: @JosephWright: The main difference between OT1 and T1 is that T1 is full: on all 256 positions there is a glyph. In OT1 there are 128 "free" position which fonts can use for special glyphs/special effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but wouldn't it be simpler to switch to the T1 encoding?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{OT1}{e}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\'e}}

\begin{document}

a\accent19 ei % the original one

a\'ei

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily extend to all desired combinations using the same pattern. Note that you can even use `\'e` in the definition, since the encoding will already be `T1` in the group, so the combination `\'e` will use the relative definition.

Comment: @Sverre The switch to T1 must be local, therefore the additional pair of braces. Notice that I simplified the definition, so you don't even have to hunt through the table to find code points.

Comment: I see. I always enclose my macros (e.g. ``{\'e}``) within brackets anyway, so the T1 encoding will be local. But I see that if I don't do that, it'll remain T1.

Comment: The reason I went through the table to find the code points was that a redefinition such as ``\renewcommand{\aa}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont{\aa}}`` didn't work. I needed to do ``\renewcommand{\aa}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont{\symbol{229}}}``.

Comment: @Sverre Of course you can't use `\aa` in the definition of `\aa`; however, `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{OT1}{e}{...}` doesn't define a `\'e` command, so using `\'e` in the body is possible, as long as the encoding is set to a different one than in the second argument.